# select query for not to showing if already assigned to orderno

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

```
Supplier
S.No | Name
1    | Arun
2    | Ram
3    | Kishore

Response
S.No | OrderNo | Supplier
1    |     001 |        1
2    |     001 |        2
3    |     002 |        3
4    |     003 |        2
```

Above is my Table.

I am writing a auto suggest option. I need a query in that for the condition,

**If a supplier is assigned for the particular order, then it should not show for that order order again**

Something like

```
select * from Supplierwhere (#don't know what to implement here)
```

How can i construct the select query accordingly ??

Comment: `select * from supplier, response where supplier.sno=response.supplier and orderno='001'` here is the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
SELECT S.No,Name FROM Supplier WHERE S.No NOT IN (SELECT Supplier FROM Response where OrderNo =001)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM supplier
WHERE S_No NOT IN (SELECT S_No FROM Response)
```

You can do it more efficiently using more complicated join conditions.